# How to specify a specific type converter for a given property using AutoMapper

Tags: automapper, typeconverter

How can I override the type converter being used by AutoMapper for a given property?

For example, if I have:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I simply want to map Foo.Name to Bar.Name but using a specified type converter. I see how I can do it using:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
    .ForMember( x => x.Name, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<FooNameResolver>() );
```

But this hard-codes the conversion to use the Name property on Foo. If I have the same type of conversion on other properties in this or other classes, I have to create a resolver class for each.

And I don't want to specify a converter for string -> string as this conversion is specific to this property or others like it.

I just want to override the type converter! I'm sure this must be possible but I'm blanking on it :-(

I'm after something like this:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
    .ForMember( x => x.Name, opt => opt.Using<MySpecialStringConverter>() );
```

Answer (score 8):

I discovered the answer reading through the unit tests for AutoMapper. It's not very obvious, despite the fluent interface, because many of the methods on the mapping options return void. However, `ResolveUsing<>()` doesn't return void but allows you to specify further options. Herein lies the solution:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Source,Dest>
    .ForMember( dest => dest.Name, 
                opt => opt.ResolveUsing<MySpecialStringConverter>()
                          .FromMember( source => source.Name ) );
```

I'd prefer not to have to specify the `.FromMember` when the property is the default which AutoMapper would use anyway and all I want to use is override the type converter/resolver.